# Condition for pair of planes in three dimensional geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, solid-geometry

We know that the equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2hxy+2fyz+2gzx=0$ represents a pair of planes if and only if $\begin{vmatrix}
a& h& g\\
h&b& f\\
g& f&c
\end{vmatrix}=0.$ I wanted to prove this result. Let the two planes be of the form  $l_1x+m_1y+n_1z=0$ and $l_2x+m_2y+n_2z=0.$ Then we have  $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2hxy+2fyz+2gzx=(l_1x+m_1y+n_1z)(l_2x+m_2y+n_2z)=0.$$ On comparing the coefficients of $x, y$ and $z$ both sides we get \begin{align*}
l_1l_2&=a\\
m_1m_2&=b\\
n_1n_2&=c\\
l_1m_2+l_2m_1&=2h\\
l_1n_2+l_2n_1&=2f\\
m_1n_2+m_2n_1&=2g.
\end{align*}
Now we have  six equations in six variables. How to show that these equations have a non-trivial solution if and only if

$\begin{vmatrix}
a& h& g\\
h&b& f\\
g& f&c
\end{vmatrix}=0?$

Comment: it is true that the quadratic factors as two linears  when your determinant is zero. However, all that is guaranteed is factoring over the complexes; in varaibles $x,y,z$     the form $x^2 + y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy);$   the (real) zero set is the $z$ axis

Comment: Hint: consider matrix multiplication $\begin{pmatrix}l_1\\m_1\\n_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}l_2&m_2&n_2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: can you plz elaborate? @JeanMarie

Comment: How do we prove that  the determinant is zero ? can  you suggest any further reading texts? @WillJagy

Comment: Compute the resulting $3 \times 3$ matrix. You will see by identifying it with your initial matrix that your system of 6 equations is verified.

Comment: @JeanMarie  it appears he is mostly asking about the determinant being zero when the quadratic form does factor (well, over the reals).  The other direction, determinant zero causes factoring (over the complexes) is a bit different;  in Schinzel, Polynomials with Special Regard to Reducibility, this is Corollary 2 on page 212.  Factoring of a homogeneous ternary cubic form is more interesting,  one result is Corollary 3 on page 213

Comment: @Will Jagy   suggest texts on classification of second order quadratic forms in three space? I am curious to prove the determinant is zero using the six equations.

Comment: user, you really should calculate the 3 by 3 matrix Jean Marie defined in his comment of about 46 minutes ago. Then calculate its transpose and add them. If you know something of matrix rank, eigenvectors, it should become clear. Write out the actual matrices

Comment: @JeanMarie When multiplying the matrices $$ \begin{bmatrix}  l_1\\  m_1\\ n_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  l_2&m_2&n_2 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}  l_1l_2 &l_1m_2& l_1n_2\\ m_1l_2& m_1m_2& m_2n_2\\ n_1l_2&n_1m_2& n_1n_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: user, if we call your  calculation something like $V W^T = U_{12}$  where $U_{12}$   is three by three, now write out $ (V W^T)^T = W V^T $  and call that $U_{21}.$   Finally write out  $U=U_{12} + U_{21}$ which is going to be symmetric.  This becomes the matrix of a quadratic form; although there are factors of 2 in various places that need to be cared for, eventually this $U$  becomes the matrix (the  Hessian matrix)  of a quadratic form.....  By construction,  rank of $U$ is no larger than 2, so determinant is zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put material on      solving $P^T M P = D$ diagonal when $M$  is real symmetric at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

The above is just an algorithm for repeated completing the square.

As far as how to do it, we are given a symmetric real matrix, call it $M.$   We may construct  a real matrix $P$   with $\det P = \pm 1$  so that $P^T M P = D$ is diagonal. With determinant $0$  this means as many as two nonzero entries in $D.$   If we take $Q = P^{-1}$   we get $Q^T D Q = M.$ If we name your quadratic form $R(x,y,z)$  we have reached
$$ \color{blue}{  R(x,y,z) = d_1 (a_1x+b_1 y + c_1z)^2  + d_2 (a_2x+b_2 y + c_2z)^2}$$

When $d_1, d_2$  are both positive or both negative, both linear expressions must be zero and the zero set is a single (real) line. When $d_1 d_2 < 0$  we see that $R(x,y,z)$ factors over the reals. One may write $$  A V^2 - B W^2 = (V \sqrt A + W \sqrt B)(V \sqrt A - W \sqrt B) $$